# Is it possible to use one Windows Server 2008 R2 to be the backup for other 2008 and 2012 servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, backup, windows-server-2012

I have taken over some sysadmin duties and am looking to do the following (if possible).

1) Setup a single Windows Server 2008 R2 as a hub for all the backups.

2) Use Windows Server Backup on this one machine to remotely connect to all the other servers and back them up.

Is this possible to do? If so how? Or is there a better way?

Note: Most of the servers are 2008 R2 but I do have one 2012 and an old 2003. All these servers are in the same rack on the same subnet so bandwidth is not an issue. I would consider these all on-site backups. Off-site backups is another story.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can [use Windows Server Backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770266%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to do this.

Comment: To be clear, one server will run a shared folder containing all the servers' backups, and all the servers run Windows Server Backup configured to backup to this shared folder.

Comment: Got a favorite tutorial on how to set this up?